# Sharepoint 2013: Field "Created By" and "Created" changed after site restore

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, backup, restore

I have a Document Library in SharePoint and when I did a Site backup and restore operation, some of the fields such as `Created by` and `Created` in this Document Library get different value. In the field `Created by` there is a name of user who made a restore (My name) and not a name who actually created it. In field "Created" there is a date when restore was made, instead of date when document was created.

I have Sharepoint Foundation, version 15.0.4420.1017.

Is this a normal behaviour of backup and restore, or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you performed the restore operation.

Comment: I did "Perform a backup" - "Restore from a backup" in Central Administration. Result is the same if i backup only Sharepoint Web Application or the whole Farm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal behavior if you are restoring it to a different site or copying to another site. If it is the same site collection and you are restoring from Recycle bin, it should retain the original values. Please provide details on your restoring process

Comment: No, restore is made to the same site. I use Central Administration "Restore from a backup" and then choose a file (on C:\Backup) to restore from.

Comment: Backup/restore this way should ideally preserve the time stamps and user security

Comment: That's what i thought too. I will try backup-restore process again on my test page and if problem persist, i'll come back to you...

Comment: It works just fine! I tried Granular backup of a test site and restore it with Powershell - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx. All document library fields were as they should be. Guess i had been doing something wrong before... Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you had performed the backup and restore of your site directly through UI or Windows explorer, and this is the expected behaviour. To preserve the Created by/ Created fields I recommend you to use **STSADM/Powershell commands** to perform backup and restore.

[Export-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx)

[Import-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx)

Utilize the parameter `IncludeUserSecurity` which will help Preserving the user security settings except for SPLists that have broken inheritance and item level permissions set.