# Restore SharePoint database with metadata

Tags: sharepoint-server, metadata, restore, database

I have a question - When you restore a SharePoint database what will happen to original metadata, such as Created by, Created and Modified by and Modified?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Metadata will persist database restore/migration.

Metadata can change while migrated using Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the fields, use Granular backup and restore it with Powershell.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Restore-SPSite?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sharepoint-ps

Similar issue post for your reference:

[Sharepoint 2013: Field "Created By" and "Created" changed after site restore](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191308/sharepoint-2013-field-created-by-and-created-changed-after-site-restore)